# What is the "working set" equivalent in intellij idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

What is eclipse "working set" equivalent in intellij idea?

my project is biiig with many many folders. Now I only work with certain subfolders where i have to read and understand code, and others that I use to add my own files. 
how can I hide folders that are not important to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no working set equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA.

There is a feature called [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/scopes.html) in IntelliJ, in which you can define a subset of folders from your project.

AFAIK, "working sets" in eclipse are NOT for selecting folders from a single project, but for building a subset of projects from a workspace.

Comment: i figured it out, i didnt see you can select the scope in the dropdown of the project tree view

Answer (score 2):

You can select one (or more) "Module" in IntelliJ and move it in a "Group" (with the option "Move module to Group".
That resemble an Eclipse "Working Set".

Answer (score 0):

You can setup eclipse-style worksets, using group of modules.

This [Group Modules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#grouping-modules) explains, how it can be done.

Comment: At the moment I have no intelli J installation for testing but I think about to get one. Can you tell me if it is possible that one project is part of multiple groups? I am asking because in a mcroservice architecture it happens that some microservices is used in multiple subviews. In eclipse I can add one project to multiple working sets for that.

Comment: @Mike as the grouping works with prefixes, one module can be in only one group at a time

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent feature of the Eclipse working sets in IntelliJ is the **groups**.

- Open File > Project Structure > Modules
- Select the modules you want to group
- Right click > Change Module Names...
- Type a module prefix

The module names get prefixed and appear in a tree, when the "Flatten Modules" display option is disabled:

[image: Flatten Modules]